# Array trouble deleting duplicates

Tags: java

This is for class homework. She is making us use array and array list in two parts. Basically she is showing us how using arraylist is alot easier than arrays.

I am having alot of trouble getting the array part to work.

> 1. Create a class called CustomerLister1 with a main method that instantiates an array of String objects called customerName. The array
>      should have room for six String objects. Use an initializer list to
>      put the following names into the array:
>
>    ```
>    Chris  
>    Lois  
>    Meg  
>    Peter  
>    Stewie
>    ```
> 2. Write an enhanced for loop to display the array of names. What is displayed for the last array element? Why is it that value?
> 3. Add the Strings "Meg" and "Brian" into index 3, and 4, respectively, so that the array contains the following elements:
>
>    ```
>    Chris  
>    Lois  
>    Meg  
>    Meg  
>    Brian  
>    Peter  
>    Stewie
>    ```
> 4. Write an enhanced for loop to display the array of names.
> 5. Write a second, traditional for loop that checks each element for the String “Meg”, if found in the array, remove it, shift the
>      remaining elements, and display the array of names. Are both instances
>      of "Meg" removed correctly from the array?

This is my code

```
public class CustomerLister1
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] customerName = new String[7];
    customerName[0] = "Chris";
    customerName[1] = "Lois";
    customerName[2] = "Meg";
    customerName[3] = "Peter";
    customerName[4] = "Stewie";

    for (int i = customerName.length-1;i > 3; i--)
    {
        customerName[i] = customerName[i - 2];
    }
    customerName[3] = "Meg";
    customerName[4] = "Brian";

    for (int m = 0; m <= customerName.length-1; m++)
    {
        if(customerName[m].equals("Meg"))
        {
            for(int j = m+1;j < customerName.length-1;j++)
            {
                customerName[j]= customerName[j-1];

            }

        }

    }

    for (String element : customerName)
    {

        System.out.println(element);
    }

}
}
```

I have tried messing with the element position. It won't print right because I have meg back to back and it replaces the first meg with the second meg. What can i do here?

Comment: It says customerlister should be 6 strings she meant 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statement like this:

```
if(customerName[m].equals("Meg"))
{
    for(int j = m;j < customerName.length;j++)
    {
        if(j < customerName.length-2) {
            customerName[j]= customerName[j+1];
        } else {
            customerName[j]="";
        }
    }
m--;
}
```

By decrementing i by 1, you'll hit the same index again.

And also AmitD is correct; you need customerName[j+1], not [j-1].

Oh, and you'll need to handle the end of the array properly; don't want to try and set customerName[6] = customerName[7] when there is no customerName[7].

Edit: Ah, you'll need to start j at m, not m+1. That way you remove the "Meg" at customerName[m] as well as moving everything ahead of it backwards.

Edit: And the while part of the loop was skipping the last element in the array.

Comment: Don't you mean to decrement `m`? Also, `customerName.length` isn't the right count for the number of names. The code will need a separate variable for how many names are valid.

Comment: If i decrement the counter it goes into an infinite loop

Comment: Right, decrement m. And a separate variable for the number of valid names would be nice, but I don't _think_ it's strictly necessary - isn't a java array going to populate itself with empty strings? Copying those over each other isn't going to hurt anything.

Comment: Ok I got the meg out of the array but it copies stewie twice now.

Comment: How should i handle the else statement

Comment: Oh, you need to replace the `j < customerName.length-1` with either `j <= customerName.length-1` or `j < customerName.length`. (I, uh, screwed this up in the comment I deleted.)

Comment: what you gave me works. The output is wrong though it removes both the megs and then adds brian peter then two empty lines and then stewie. I need the empty lines to be gone and the output to print continously

Comment: I'm sorry I get lost in all these nested loops and if statements

Answer (score 0):

If you're only removing one of the `Meg`s, it might be because you've skipped over the second one.

After you've shifted the elements after the removal, what element do you check next according to your code?  Is it the one you need to check?

Answer (score 0):

Not only you have to shift one element to the left but also put a nil value at the last index. So, i would propose something like

```
for(int j = m+1;j < customerName.length-1;j++)
{
    customerName[j]= customerName[j+1];
}
customerName[customerName.length-1] = "";
```